# Apple TV Product Page Wallpaper?

Tags: app-store, tvos, apple-tv

I've submitted an app to Apple, and by default, the TV app icon seems to be scaled up and blurred to use as the background of the app page in the store. Given the design of this app icon, it doesn't look good.

I've seen other apps, Netflix and Disney+, using wallpapers that they designed themselves. Any idea where these are uploaded? Or are they baked into the actual app?

Answer (score 1):

Apple "invites/features" specific developers and enables this feature in App Store Connect. ("Promo images") You cannot enable this yourself.